# How to manage database configurations for different projects in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase project that I use as backend for my mobile app. This uses cloud functions which write to and read from the realtime database. I recently had the need to deploy these to a new environment I use for development so that I can continue working on my app without accidentally breaking my users' experience.

My firebaserc file now looks as follows:

```
{
    "projects": {
        "prod": "my-cool-app",
        "dev": "my-cool-app-dev"
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having right now is that my database configuration is hardcoded in the code itself as below:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSomething something",
    authDomain: "my-cool-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-cool-app.firebaseio.com/"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Because this does not change no matter what project I deploy, it means that both Production and Development end up writing to the same database.

I tried to search how to handle different database configurations but had no luck.

Comment: Where does the JavaScript code that you shared get executed? If it's in Cloud Functions, can you share the minimum complete index.js that shows how you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has added this config data to each domain individually. You can find it here https://yourDomain/__/firebase/init.json

Read this blog post to understand how to user it: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html

Comment: That's great for web but I'm using cloud functions that are not called through a web interface.

Comment: cloud functions configure with the following command `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`

But first you need to load `import * as functions from "firebase-functions";` and 
`import * as admin from "firebase-admin";`